# I want make JS toggle button.. How Can I Fix It?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="icon-menu">
      <img src="../images/menu.png" id="navMenu" onclick="changeToCross()">
</div>
```

JS

```
function changeToCross() {
    let menu = document.getElementById('navMenu');
    let src = '../images/menu.png'; 

    if (menu.src === src) {
        menu.src = '../images/close.svg';
    } else {
        menu.src = src;
    }
}
```

I want to change image source when it will be clicked but this code isn't working. How can I fix it

Comment: Please provide your HTML code as well

Comment: Does it print any errors to the browser console?

Comment: @LNTR No there is no error

Comment: @TanishqS Provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `element.src` is returning fully resolved URL, not the string that you're setting. For example, if you're on `https://example.com/demo/page` and use `src="../images/menu.png"` then `menu.src` would return `https://example.com/demo/images/menu.png` instead of the relative path.

In order to read the attribute value, you need to use `element.getAttribute('src')` which returns the raw value of the attribute.

So your code should be

```
if (menu.getAttribute('src') === src) {
```

To read up more on the topic, you can check what is the difference between *properties* and *attributes* in DOM.

Comment: I got two methods and another one is replacing `if (menu.src === src)` to `if (menu.src.endsWith('menu.png'))`. It is also working

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, keeping the image sources away from the Javascript, might be to use `dataset` attributes to store the alternative image source and toggle between that and the source.

```js
document.querySelector('div.icon-menu img').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  let img=e.target;
      img.dataset.tmp=img.src;
      img.src=img.dataset.alt;
      img.dataset.alt=img.dataset.tmp;
      img.removeAttribute('data-tmp');
})
```

```css
.icon-menu img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
img[src$='svg']{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-menu">
  <img src="../images/menu.png" data-alt='https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178323/cross-close.svg' id="navMenu">
</div>
```